# Get all file paths from a certain point and pipe to text file

Tags: command-line

If my terminal is currently in `home/stuff/stuff2` and there are more folders and files under `stuff2`, how can I launch a command to get the file names of all the files and folders from this directory and onwards (Including all sub directories).

The operation needs to do the following:

1. The file path must start at the location of the terminal command, so I don't want full files paths. Example, instead of the read out being `home/stuff/stuff2/stuff3/cat.png` I would prefer the read out to be `stuff3/cat.png`
2. It must capture every file and folder and files within those folders.
3. It needs to be piped (I think this is the term) to a text file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the names of the directories by themselves, or just the files in the directories?  ie, do you want, for example, "Music", "Music/file1.mp3", ..., "Pictures", "pic1.jpg", ...

Comment: @joseph Why not just running `find *` (?) if you are in `home/stuff/stuff2` directory?

Comment: By the way, if you're talking about running a command with output to a file, the more correct term is _redirecting_. Strictly speaking, _piping_ refers to running a command with its output going directly to the input of another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
find -printf "%P\n" > file
```

will list all files and directories below the current directory and *redirect* the list to `file`. From the `printf` section of `man find`

```
  %P     File's name with the name of the command  line  argument
         under which it was found removed.
```

Comment: `find -printf "%P\n" > file` will also print the directory names by themselves.  I suggest you use the switch I specified, `-type f`, to only list filenames.

Comment: @MartyFried the OP specifically asks for "a command to get the file names of all the files **and folders**"

Comment: Granted.  I assumed he meant the contents of the folders, but that could be incorrect.  Hopefully, he will comment or edit his question to clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `find`, it is also possible to do this with just the `bash` shell:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf "%s\n" ** >file
```

All output file names are printed *relative* to the current directory.

`shopt -s globstar` enables `globstar` which gives `bash` some of the power of `find`.  With `globstar`, two stars in a row will, as `man bash` states, "match all files  and  zero or  more directories and subdirectories."  Here, `printf` is used to format the file names one to a line.  The output is sent to a text file called `file`.

#### File names with special characters

This question asks for output in a text file.  Text files generally have lines separated by newline characters.  If any file or directory name itself contains a newline character, this will lead to confusion.  Unless it is known that no such file exists, it is better to use a null-separated file, not a newline-separated text file.

In this case, one can use:

```
printf "%s\000" ** >file
```

Or,

```
find -print0 >file
```

Since the nul character (ascii 000) is never allowed in a filename, this is the one format that can be used to store file names in a file without danger of losing information.

Comment: If you want to include names that begin with a dot (`.`), you must also `shopt -s dotglob`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle file in the form "./dir/filename", then a simple form of the find command would work:
`find . -type f > filename` will pipe all files below the current directory into "filename".

After seeing @steeldriver's answer, a combination of his solution and mine would eliminate the "./" prefix, like so:

If you do *not* want blank directory names in the list (ie, just the file names in each directory,
`find -type f -printf "%P\n" > file`

If you actually *do* want the directory names by themselves along with the directory/filenames, then omit the "-type f" flag from all the examples.

Comment: OP want both directory names and files. so remove the `-type f`

Comment: @KasiyA: We don't really know that.  I have found that for a very large percentage of questions by novices, they are not worded in such a way that you can take them literally, word for word.  Your interpretation is different than mine, but until I hear differently, I will not assume one or the other is what he actually wanted.

Comment: yes that's right. He said "**file names** of all the **files** and **folders** from this directory". this sentence of him is unclear.  but I think he wants all files and folders name _according to his accepted answer_.